# How to update image in UI Toolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to update Image view with new texture?

```cs
_image = new UnityEngine.UIElements.Image();
_image.image = new Texture2D(_size.value.x, _size.value.y);
//...
_image.image = texture;
//_image.Refresh(); <---- does not exist.
```

Or I using not valid control? All I want is to show bitmap image to user in UI Toolkit. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

using sprite works for me:

```
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

Image _image = new UnityEngine.UIElements.Image();

Sprite mySprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);
           
_image.sprite = mySprite;
```